# How to convert mathematical expression to lambda function in C++?

Tags: c++, function, parsing, lambda, c++17

I am trying to convert string of mathematical expression to lambda function in C++17. How can I do this type of conversion with function?

```
std::function<void()> str2lambda(const std::string& str) {
    // Conversion
    // return lambda function
}
```

Example:

> Input Mathematical function:
> "x^2+1"
>
> Output Lambda Function:
> `auto func = [](float x) -> float { return pow(x, 2) + 1; };`

Comment: Why do you need a lambda? Why can't you make it a normal function? And what is the problem with the lambda you show?

Comment: the code you show seems perfectly fine. Except maybe I would do `x * x` instead of `pow`.

Comment: You already showed exactly how to do that.

Comment: Or are you trying to parse arbitrary mathematical expression?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to parse mathematical expression.

Comment: Go read about the [shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm). Or if `^` is the only custom operator in there, you might be able to get away with just finding those and replacing them with `pow` or whatever.

Comment: What is your actual goal with the parsing? Remember that C++ is a compiled language, you can't create functions (even lambdas) at run-time. Are you parsing some input to generate C++ code to be built later (kind of like a ["transpiler"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler))? An actual compiler for a language? An interpreter which should parse and execute at run-time? In other words, what is your actual assignment? Please include it in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands, its not going to be possible since the return type of the function is dependent on a runtime argument - the compiler cannot determine what is the return type of the function.

On a side but slightly related note, there is a talk in cppcon23 about symbolic calculus, which relates to how symbols and expressions can be represented in C++: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPfA4SFojao